# how to allow mic/camera in edge web browse suing selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-edgedriver

we have  options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream") to send fake media to chrome.
Is there any such option available for edgedriver? and if what are those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one can allow mic/video in edge using

```
option = Options()
#capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.EDGE.copy()

option.set_capability("dom.webnotifications.enabled", 1)
option.set_capability("permissions.default.microphone", 1)
option.set_capability("permissions.default.camera", 1)

print type(option)


op= option.to_capabilities()

driver = webdriver.Edge(capabilities=op)
```