# How can I allow mic and camera permissions in microsoft edge using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge, ui-automation, microsoft-edge-chromium

I want to allow mic and camera in microsoft edge using selenium.

[image: See below image]

Comment: For Java: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484932/7058266

Comment: this page might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560074/how-to-allow-mic-camera-in-edge-web-browse-suing-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code below **FOR CHROME**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
preferences = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": False,
               "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": False,}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Note: `False` is used to deny access and `True` is used to allow access

Refer the code below **FOR EDGE**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

edge_options = Options()
preferences = {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
}

for name, value in preferences.items():
    edge_options.add_argument(f"--{name}={value}")

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Note: `1` is used to deny access and `2` is used to allow access

Comment: This is specific to google chrome. I want it for microsoft edge.

Comment: Check the updated answer for `Edge`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: edge_options.add_argument method is no more available in EdgeOptions

Comment: What version of selenium do you use? If possible, try to upgrade to latest selenium.

Comment: Yes, selenium version is older. Actually I am using katalon studio and they are using 3.1.x selenium version in it's latest version.